# How to Automatic Backups of a MySQL Database

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, time-machine, osx-server, mysql

I am using the version of MySQL that came with Snow Leopard Server. I am running Time Machine on that server, but I know that it's not backing up the MySQL databases due to strict permissions issues.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a non-commandline, easy, clean method for automated backups of MySQL data?

Answer (score 2):

Its not exactly what your looking for, but we used automator to create a launchable application that runs a commandline to export the sql database. We then used crontab to schedule the app to run at certain intervals.

1. In automator add the "Run Shell Script" action. Set the shell to "/bin/bash" and add the command

   > /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h localhost -uMySQLUSERNAME -pMySQLPASSWORD DatabaseName --single-transaction  > "/path/to/export/exportname"
2. Save the workflow as an application, then use crontab to schedule the application (or you can use [Cronnix](http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/) - GUI for crontab)

This is also a good method beacause you can put the application on the dock and anyone can run the backup on-demand. We have software monitor the folder where we export the databse to and when it detects changes it uploads the new file to our backup server. Works a treat

Not as simple to set up as your probably looking for, but it works well once its set up!